# concave conical lenses on 5050 SMD LEDs?

Tags: led, light, optics

Is there any way to put plano-convex conical lenses, or something broadly equivalent, on 5050 SMD LEDs?

The lenses I'm talking about are the type commonly built into cheap christmas-tree lights:

[image: LEDs with concave cone-shaped lenses]
[image: Light distribution from concave lenses]

As you can see in the second picture, these lenses distribute quite a lot of the light "horizontal" to the alignment of the LED, with fairly little light going normal to the LED. All other LED lenses I've seen, even those meant to diffuse the light as evenly as possible, have a "hot spot" centered directly above the LED.

The reason I'm asking is, I'm trying to build something not unlike what's depicted in this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9nSbWEA1jI), which depicts an led-backlit art project. I want to make something similar, but much thinner, which means I need to diffuse the light from the LEDs much more evenly - or else, use a lot more LEDs, which isn't practical in my case.

Comment: Those LEDs produce the "sideways" light not from a lens effect, but from strong internal reflection off the conical depression. You won't get this from an added external lens.

Comment: tear apart a scrap LCD computer monitor .... you will find a light diffuser panel between the LCD and the backlight lamps

Comment: You will need many zone LEDs and diffuser panels to achieve 500 lumens/sq.m typical LED backlight display.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, true, with the depicted LEDs, the conical depression is in a piece of plastic that has been permanently molded to the LED itself. But there's no reason you couldn't take a bare LED and add an equivalent plastic piece. The light should enter the plastic "lens" (in quotes because I think it's really more like a prism) just fine, perpendicular to the bottom surface, and if the cone angle is right internal reflection should direct most of the light out the sides.